# Array index out of bounds exception 2 Java and other errors

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

Compiled this code via cmd line creating Bar.Class

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Bar {
    private static final String[][] pos = 
            new String[][] {{"X0","Y0"},{"X1","Y1"},{"X2","Y2"}};

    public Bar() {}

    public static String getAtPosition(int x, int y) {
        return pos[x][y];
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Bar bar = new Bar();

        try {
            for (int x = 0; x < pos.length; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < pos.length; y++) {
                    System.out.println(bar.getAtPosition(x,y));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

getting the following errors when entering **java Bar**

```
X0
Y0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at Bar.getAtPosition<Bar.java:12>
at Bar.main<Bar.java:23>
```

This code was provided by a company with whom I have an interview with they require comments explaining each source line and the results of the program when ran.

any help would be appreciated, I've only been learning java for a few days and I've spent hours on this today.

Comment: Giving the answer on an interview test would be cheating.  I would point you in the right direction by asking you to look at pos.  It is a matrix, but what is the size of the matrix?  That might help you understand the issue.

Comment: Check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000169/getting-the-array-length-of-a-2d-array-in-java) for the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link on 2d arrays and the I will take a look at the matrix size as suggested. I'm not trying to cheat though just trying to use all my resources to show that I can solve a problem. :-)

Comment: The question also asks to explain the exception in the results then it asks what line causes the exception? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The inner array doesn't have `pos.length` elements. It has `pos[0].length` elements.

Try :

```
        for (int x = 0; x < pos.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < pos[0].length; y++) {
                System.out.println(bar.getAtPosition(x,y));
            }
        }
```

That said, it doesn't make much sense having a method `getAtPosition` in order to access elements of your private static array, and then to directly access the private array in order to find the range of the array indices you can pass to that method.

Comment: It's telling me to explain an exception in the results and the line that caused it. The results don't seem to have an exception going x0 y0 x1 y1 x2 y2

Comment: @This_isWater `getAtPosition(0,2)` would give you an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions, since your array has three rows but only two columns.

Comment: @This_isWater If you fixed your code as I suggested, you won't get this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below

```
for (int y = 0; y < pos.length; y++)
```

with this statement

```
for (int y = 0; y < pos[x].length; y++)
```

**output**

```
X0
Y0
X1
Y1
X2
Y2
```