# Manipulating an int[][] Array with bit operators JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception, bit-shift

I need to take an int[][] array and shift bits 0-6 one position to the left, while saving bit 7 and setting bit 0 to the previously saved value of bit 7; for each location [row][col] in the array. I have some code that I feel like is right on the verge of this, but I am missing something and I cannot figure out what:

```
    int[][] temp = someArray;
    for(int row = 0; row < someArray.length; ++row)
        for(int col = 0; col < someArray [row].length; ++col)
        {
            int num = someArray[row][j];
            int numAtSeven = num & (1 << 7);

            num = num << 1; //shift
            numAtSeven = numAtSeven >> 7; //move to end
            num = num | numAtSeven; //put back in
            System.out.println(row + " = " + col);
            System.out.println(num);
            temp[row][j] = num;
        }
    System.out.println("out");
    someArray = temp;
```

still ArrayOutOfIndex, produces the following output:

```
    0 = 0
    279
    0 = 1
    324
    0 = 1
    .
    .
    .
    326 = 1
    359
    326 = 2
    301
    326 = 3
    .
    .
    .

    329
    327 = 499
    357
    out
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 285
```

Additionally, I need to take the same array and exchange the bottom 2 bits with the top 2 bits for each [row][col], and I am pretty lost on this portion too. I know that I will need a nested for loop again, and that it will be very similar to, if not a mirror of, the above process but this is really stumping me.

I did search for this first, and found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331213/how-to-do-certain-things-to-2d-images), but I do not understand that code really either, and it still doesn't answer my first question.

edit: running the code throws a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

edit2: updated code to reflect changes

Comment: You need to state what error you get!

Comment: how do you calculate height and width? if the second dimension does not have the same size all the time then you might get your IndexOutOfBoundException.

Comment: oops...I meant to I've added it

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000169/getting-the-array-length-of-a-2d-array-in-java

Comment: @KevinEsche they are defined above in my code, but it is a square array. Each element in the array corresponds to a location [row][col] in a picture, say 256x512 or something.

Comment: @lexlcon `256x512` is not a square matrix... a square matrix has equal height and width. You should use `matrix[col][row]` instead - look at my answer.

Comment: I suggest decomposing your problem into two subproblems, iterating over the matrix and doing the bit manipulation. You can write and test iterating over the array with a simple System.out.println in the loop.

Comment: @lexIcon `out` was printed - I don't think its this part of the code that is throwing the exception.

Comment: yeah, I was afraid of that lol thanks everyone for helping tho

Answer (score 1):

Probably because `height` and `width` are incorrect and so you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Try:

```
for(int row = 0; row < someArray.length; ++row)
    for(int col = 0; col < someArray[row].length; ++col)
```

For a matrix `m`:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, ... , 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, ... , 0],
         ...
 [0, 0, 0, 0, ... , 0]]
```

`m[1][2]` would be labeled with `M`:

```
m[x][y] --------y----------
        0  1  2  3  ...   m
|  0  [[0, 0, 0, 0, ... , 0],
x  1   [0, 0, M, 0, ... , 0],
|  2           ...
|  n   [0, 0, 0, 0, ... , 0]]
```

So you might have accidentally used `someArray[y][x]` instead of `someArray[x][y]`, thus getting the out of bounds exception.

Comment: that did not work :( it seems to error out here if I step through a break point: 
someArray[row][col] = entireNum;

Comment: @lexIcon still `IndexOutOfBounds`? Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: @lexIcon Also please update your code to reflect any changes you just made.