# Filling 2D Array in Java and getting ExceptionOutOfBounds

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I searched some entries, but could not answer my question correctly myself.

I'm trying to fill a 2-dimensional array with values.
As a test I'm currently doing this by trying to fill the array with the int number 1.

I do not understand my mistake.

```
public static void creatBoard () { 
        
        final int L = 6; 
        final int H = 6; 
        
        // Modell: 
        
        int [] [] board = new int [L] [H]; 
        for (int i = 0; i<=board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<=board.length; j++) {
                board [i] [j] = 1; 
            }
            System.out.println("");
            
            
        }
```

Comment: The index of an array starts at 0. You created an array of size 6, so your array indexes range from 0...5. Your loops go from 0, ... 6 (because of the `<=` notation). So when your loop reaches index 6, your array goes OutOfBounds.

Answer (score 1):

Use index 0 to length-1 (as array index start with 0)

```
    public static void creatBoard () { 
            
            final int L = 6; 
            final int H = 6; 
            
            // Modell: 
            
            int [] [] board = new int [L] [H]; 
            for (int i = 0; i<board.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j<board[i].length; j++) {
                    board [i] [j] = 1; 
                }
                System.out.println("");           
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just debug it and you can see, that

```
for (int i = 0; i<=board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<=board.length; j++) {
            board [i] [j] = 1; 
        }
        System.out.println("");
        
        
    }
```

i, and j change values from 0 to 6, it means that it get's out of arrays bounds ( you iterate over 7 lements, instead of 6 ), just remove `=` sign in loop bodies

```
for (int i = 0; i<board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<board[i].length; j++) {
            board [i] [j] = 1; 
        }
        System.out.println("");     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your board array is of size 6x6 hence the **board.length** is 6.

When you run the loop **for (int j = 0; j<=board.length; ij+)** it will run from 0 up to 6 but the array indexing is from 0 to 5. So when j=6, **ExceptionOutOfBounds** occurs since it will be referring to index **board[0][6]**.

Change the condition in both the loops from **<=board.length** to **<board.length**

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have one more little question. If I have a 2 D `array int [][] = board = new [6][7] `what is the `.length `? 
Is it the 6 or the 7

Comment: @forty4seven When you do array.length it gives you the number of rows in the array. If you array is [6] [7], the array.length would give you 6. If you want the length of a specific row then you need to do columnLength=array[0].length .. Look here for more details : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000169/getting-the-array-length-of-a-2d-array-in-java