# Ignoring ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, performance, exception

I have an over-complicated hyper-dimensional array.
When retrieving data from it, I am just putting it between a try-catch block which ignores any `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Like this:

```java
try {
   return data[/* Math here*/];
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored)
{
  return null;
}
```

Is that bad practise?
Does that have any impact on performance/does it mess something up?
Is it more performant to code a proper check algorithm or does it even have negative impact?

What do you think?

Comment: Yes, it's bad practice in my view. Yes, it could easily have an impact on performance if it's happening frequently (as ever with performance questions: test to make sure). What's stopping you from taking the bounds of the data into account when working out how to access it?

Comment: If for general use you should explain the requirements of the array and throw your own exceptions which describe what might have caused the error.  If possible, use field names and values in the message to help clarify the problem.  This helps folks (including you) debug their code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not ignore `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because it may result in performance issues and it's obviously a bad practice in java so you should store the size of the array(multidimensional sizes) so that you can check the bounds before accessing the array values if in your case this seems to be a dynamic array or a `jagged array` so you need to figure out the size of the array before starting to access it and best way to figure out the size. [Find 2D Array size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000169/getting-the-array-length-of-a-2d-array-in-java)

1. Later on, you will face lot's of Null pointer exception if you will
   be using these arrays values and performing any action on them.
2. It will waste user time getting values from the index which don't exist, but index access also takes less time i.e Constant time.