# Get size of second dimension while first dimension is empty

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I want to know the size of the second dimension but the first dimension needs to be 0. Of course this array cannot store any elements and is therefore useless, but the size of the first dimension will later be changed with an `arrayCopy` method.

```
String[][] arr = new String[0][3];

// Get the first dimension size
System.out.println(arr.length); // 0

// Get the second dimension size
System.out.println(arr[0].length; // Out of bounds error
```

Comment: You can't. Java arrays are not really square, they are so-called jagged arrays, meaning each and every nested array can have its own length. If you declare the first dimension to be length zero, there is no second dimension, and even if it had a length of 1 or larger, you shouldn't rely on the length of the first (or any other) nested array to infer the length of all nested arrays.

Comment: Related: [Getting the array length of a 2D array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000169/getting-the-array-length-of-a-2d-array-in-java)